# Row Select Not Working in Django Using JS

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have a table, in which I would like the user to be able to select rows - i.e. upon clicking on the row, it would become active.  I took some javascript example from online and amended it to my code, but it is still not working.  Any advice what I need to change? I used active instead of selected because bootstrap is being leveraged in this example.

.html

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="main_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width="50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th style="width:3%;">Reference</th>
      <th style="width:7%;">Ultimate Consignee</th>
      <th style="width:7%;">Vessel</th>
      <th style="width:7%;">Booking #</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">POL</th>
      <th style="width:15%;">DOL</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">POE</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">Pickup #</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">Sales Contact</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">Trucking Co</th>
      <th style="width:2%;">Total Cases</th>
      <th style="width:2%;">Total FOB</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">Freight Forwarder</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    {% for orders in orders %}

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="{% url 'edit_shipment' orders.pk %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
      </td>

      <td>{{ orders.reference }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.ultimate_consignee }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.vessel }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.booking_no }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.POL }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.DOL }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.POE }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.pickup_no }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.sales_contact }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.trucking_co }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.total_cases }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.total_fob }}</td>
      <td>{{ orders.freight_forwarder }}</td>

    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fulltable.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


<script>
  $('#main_table').DataTable();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#main_table').DataTable();

    $('#main_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } );

} );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you inspect the DOM does the `.active` class appear in the class list of the `<tr>` node?

Comment: @Halcyon I see that it is toggling between ```class="odd active"``` and ```class="odd"``` when I click an odd row.  But there is no indication in the UI that the row is selected.

Comment: @Halcyon so with that said what am I missing to make the row appear selected? Does this need to be achieved using some CSS?

Comment: Then check that you've configured the `.active` rule in your CSS accordingly, maybe part of the selector is not matching?

Answer (score 0):

This part of code will add or remove `.active` in current tr clicked.

If you click 2 different tr both will have `.active`

```
$('#main_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

it should be something like this

```
var table = $('#main_table').DataTable();
$('#main_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```